How to set Client idle connection timeout in IBM MQ?
I am building a springboot application with a connection to an IBM MQ server which I don't have control over. I also monitor my app using the actuator health. The actuator uses the default JmsHealthIndicator to indicate the health of the connection to the IBM MQ server.
So, I set up some alerts to check the /actuator/health of the application.
Happy Scenario:
I start the application, and the /actuator/health endpoint shows that the health status is UP because the MQ is also up. While the MQ server is down, the /actuator/health endpoint shows DOWN too.
Strange Scenario:
When the application is running, the MQ server sometimes is down without disconnecting the connection. So, the server is down for 5 mins, and the /actuator/health delays the response for 5 mins until the MQ server is up again.
How can I set up on the client side to set a timeout for such a scenario? What timeout should I set?

What is the HBINT of the SVRCONN channel?

Use heartbeating

@JoshMc 300 seconds. Thanks for your comment. It looks it is impossible to change it to shorter HBINT in client side.

The heartbeating value that will be used is the least frequent interval from the configuration at the two ends. If you want to reduce it, reduce the value on the SVRCONN.

@MoragHughson, I don't have control in the server side.

Then you can't make the heartbeating more frequent than the SVRCONN has set. Changing the heartbeat interval value on the client (which can be done) will not make it more frequent than that which is set on the server.

This provides more details on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696918/7264620

Thanks @JoshMc. My scenario is also mentioned in the question. If the server was up and reachable over the network and only the MQ listener (or all of MQ) was shutdown then the response from the server to a connection to the MQ listener port would be an immediate "Connection refused" and you would never hit the TCP Connection Timeout. Properly we need to terminate the connection with some custom timeout in program then.
